# Anyway to get old ui in blender 2.8?

Tags: 3d-view

Is it possible to get blender 2.79 UI into blender 2.8? Im not used to the new ui and i prefer the old one, so is there a way i can get the ui to be like the old one?

Comment: It might help if you can mention which specific things you would like to change. There isn't a single button to turn the new UI off, but there may be small, individual changes which can help.

Comment: honestly it would be great if i can get rid of the side selection bar, and get the old menu back, the one with render settings, materials, scene, ect..thats pretty much the two big ones